# Oozie editor in HUE doesn't show workflows I submited by oozie command

Tags: oozie, cloudera-cdh, hue

I submited a workflow and run the job by oozie command:

```
oozie job -oozie http://node1:11000/oozie -config job.properties -submit
oozie job -oozie http://node1:11000/oozie -start [job_id]
```

it worked well.
And I wanted to edit the workflow by oozie editor in HUE but couldn't find it. What shall I do to make the workflow shown in oozie editor?
CDH version: 5.9

Comment: _"Oozie editor in HUE"_ is part of Hue, and stores its metadata in the DB schema used by Hue. I think it is possible to "import" a job definition in XML format -- in theory. But in practice, Hue has so many limitations that it would probably fail _(disclaimer: I keep as far away from this piece of *%!!§ as I can, maybe it's now a half-decent editor, but 2 years ago it was just useless)_

Comment: I see. Maybe it's not neccesary to use oozie editor. Can you just add the comment to the answer, so I can finish this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend o use `HUE` for editing workflows. As it uses set of metadata stored in DB and owned by itself it will not allow you to introduce changes into workflow submitted from the outside.

`Hue` is pretty nice tool for prototyping and monitoring the workflow/coordinator progress, checking the logs and having a first view in case of any issue investigation. You can import your xml and allow editing via GUI - http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-import-a-pre-existing-oozie-workflow-into-hue/ , but this is hard to manage and maintain in production like environments. For example running multiple instances of the workflow with various parameters.

Comment: Got it ! Thank you for your answer.